# T-SQL: Is it possible two have two separate RAISERROR messages output to the same line?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a rather large query that does quite a few things and I would like to improve the progress messaging. Within this query there are multiple main "processes" and each of those processes have their entire workload split over multiple passes so if something fails to complete, not everything is rolled back. As it sits, the progress messages I have only shows when each of the main processes start and when each pass within each process finishes. I would like to show something like `(1 of 16) Rebuilding X...` when the pass starts and then `Complete! Took Xh:Xm:Xs.xxx` when the pass finishes.

While I can definitely do just that, I can't seem to find a way to put those two messages on the same line without buffering either message. What I would like to see is:

```
(1 of 16) Rebuilding X... Complete! Took Xh:Xm:Xs.xxx
```

Instead of:

```
(1 of 16) Rebuilding X...
Complete! Took Xh:Xm:Xs.xxx
```

Both `RAISERROR` and `PRINT` inherently add a newline after the message and I can't seem to find a way around it. I tried using the line-continuation character `\` and also the backspace character `CHAR(8)` to remove the newline, but that does not appear to work across multiple `PRINT` or `RAISERROR` commands.

Any pointers? The target instances could be as old as SQL Server 2008 R2 so please keep compatibility in mind. If something for 2008 R2 is not possible but is for newer versions, please do let me know that as well!

Comment: Nope. New output buffer will go on a new line, unless you want to wait to push it all out together.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Interesting to know! SSMS isn't exactly intended to be used in this way so that makes sense. Maybe i'll get bored sometime and build some small external application with a GUI that can handle the progress reporting however I desire, who knows!